# JavaScript Validation for top level domain of email address

Tags: javascript, email

I am trying to create some JavaScript validation to only allow the input of a top level domain of an email address. e.g.(@gmail.com)

I have used the snippet below to try and form validation around the input, however it still allows full email addresses to be input. e.g. (mark@gmail.com)

```
function isEmailDomain(emailDomainVar) {
  var regEmail = new RegExp('@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/');
  return regEmail.test(emailDomainVar);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any input on this issue!

Comment: This will work for you   ^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@g(oogle)?mail\.com$

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me :( Also, would like to have more domains than just gmail if possible

Comment: If you have a fixed list of domains you want to allow, then why use regex in the first place ... put them into an array, and then check if what was input by the user, is present in the array. (Whether you split the leading `@` off of the user input first, or insert all values into your array with a leading `@` - up to you …)

Comment: I got it working in the end thanks to the answer below. I was missing the symbol ^ from my validation rule.

The reason why I didn't want it to restrict specific domain names, was the fact that the purpose of the input field was to block out the first portion of the email address for example 'Josh' in the email josh@gmail.com. 

I think I was a little unclear about that in my initial explanation,  so I do apologise for that, but thank you for all your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a symbol for matching the beginning of the imput: `^`. Simply add it in the beginning of your regex:

```
function isEmailDomain(emailDomainVar){
  var regEmail = /^@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  return regEmail.test(emailDomainVar);
}
```

Here is [MDN docs ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) for further reading.